# Erlang: choosing unique items from a list, using recursion

Tags: recursion, erlang

Given any list in Erlang, e.g.:

```
L = [foo, bar, foo, buzz, foo].
```

How can I only show the unique items of that list, using a recursive function?
I do not want to use an built-in function, like one of the lists functions (if it exists).

In my example, where I want to get to would be a new list, such as

```
SL = [bar, buzz].
```

My guess is that I would first sort the list, using a quick sort function, before applying a filter?

Any suggestions would be helpful. The example is a variation of an exercise in chapter 3 of Cesarini's & Thompson's excellent "Erlang Programming" book.

Comment: Thanks for your edits. I'm new to Stack Overflow, so appreciated the suggestions / style guide.

Comment: @Muzaaya Joshua: I would like to only show the unique items of that list, as opposed to merely removing the duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I propose this one:

```
unique(L) ->
    unique([],L).
unique(R,[]) -> R; 
unique(R,[H|T]) ->
    case member_remove(H,T,[],true) of
        {false,Nt} -> unique(R,Nt);
        {true,Nt} -> unique([H|R],Nt)
    end.

member_remove(_,[],Res,Bool) -> {Bool,Res};
member_remove(H,[H|T],Res,_) -> member_remove(H,T,Res,false);
member_remove(H,[V|T],Res,Bool) -> member_remove(H,T,[V|Res],Bool).
```

The member_remove function returns in one pass the remaining tail without all occurrences of the element being checked for duplicate and the test result.

Comment: Very elegant. Works beautifully. Thanks very much for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

I may do it this way :)

```
get_unique(L) ->
    SortedL = lists:sort(L),
    get_unique(SortedL, []).

get_unique([H | T], [H | Acc]) ->
    get_unique(T, [{dup, H} | Acc]);
get_unique([H | T], [{dup, H} | Acc]) ->
    get_unique(T, [{dup, H} | Acc]);
get_unique([H | T], [{dup, _} | Acc]) ->
    get_unique(T, [H | Acc]);
get_unique([H | T], Acc) ->
    get_unique(T, [H | Acc]);
get_unique([], [{dup, _} | Acc]) ->
    Acc;
get_unique([], Acc) ->
    Acc.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think idea might be: check if you already seen the head of list. If so, skip it and recursively check the tail. If not - add current head to results, to 'seen' and recursively check the tail. Most appropriate structure for checking if you already have seen the item is set.

So,i'd propose following:

```
 remove_duplicates(L) -> remove_duplicates(L,[], sets:new()). 

  remove_duplicates([],Result,_) -> Result;
  remove_duplicates([Head|Tail],Result, Seen) ->
    case sets:is_element(Head,Seen) of
      true -> remove_duplicates(Tail,Result,Seen);
      false -> remove_duplicates(Tail,[Head|Result], sets:add_element(Head,Seen))
    end.
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code example does indeed remove the duplicates, but at the same time does not return only the unique items from the list?

Comment: oh, I see. You need elements that appear one and only one time in the list. In that case I believe you dont need recursive function at all. You just need to count each item and filter elements where counter = 1. Like `D = lists:foldl( fun(X,Acc) -> dict:update_counter(X,1,Acc) end, dict:new(), List), [X|| {X,1} <- dict:to_list(D)].`

Comment: or even better: `[X||{X,1} <- dict:to_list(lists:foldl( fun(X,Acc) -> dict:update_counter(X,1,Acc) end, dict:new(), List))].`

Answer (score 1):

Use two accumulators. One to keep elements you have seen so far, one to hold the actual result. If you see the item for the first time (not in Seen list) prepend the item to both lists and recurse. If you have seen the item before, remove it from your result list (Acc) before recursing.

```
-module(test).

-export([uniques/1]).

uniques(L) ->
    uniques(L, [], []).

uniques([], _, Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc);
uniques([X | Rest], Seen, Acc) ->
    case lists:member(X, Seen) of
        true -> uniques(Rest, Seen, lists:delete(X, Acc));
        false -> uniques(Rest, [X | Seen], [X | Acc])
    end.
```

Comment: I wonder who did -1 to proper solution? The only thing that bothers me in it is use of `lists:delete/2` when item is already known to be not unique. I suppose you can have two lists `NotUnique` and `UniqueByNow` that don't have intersections. And you'll have to check X membership in both of them.

Comment: Maybe slightly less elegant, but a proper solution nevertheless. +1

Comment: I do like the accumulator idea - as a general principle in Erlang. Hadn't thought about this before. Thank you for suggesting.

Comment: @DmitryBelyaev I think you need lists:delete/2 even if you do it the way to propose to remove the item from UniqueByNow when you see the item for the 2nd time. Right?

Comment: Yes. I just didn't like `true -> uniques(Rest, Seen, lists:delete(X, Acc));` for elements that was seen more than 2 times. There will be no X in Acc in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
unique(List) ->
    Set = sets:from_list(List),
    sets:to_list(Set).
```

Comment: To improve your answer should be better if you add a description text about the solution

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

This solution only filters out duplicates from a list. probably requires building upon to make it do what you want.

```
remove_duplicates(List)->
    lists:reverse(removing(List,[])).

removing([],This) -> This;
removing([A|Tail],Acc) -> 
    removing(delete_all(A,Tail),[A|Acc]).

delete_all(Item, [Item | Rest_of_list]) ->
    delete_all(Item, Rest_of_list);
delete_all(Item, [Another_item| Rest_of_list]) ->
    [Another_item | delete_all(Item, Rest_of_list)];
delete_all(_, []) -> [].
```

**EDIT**

---

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>erl
Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
1> List = [1,2,3,4,a,b,e,r,a,b,v,3,2,1,g,{red,green},d,2,5,6,1,4,6,5,{red,green}].
[1,2,3,4,a,b,e,r,a,b,v,3,2,1,g,
 {red,green},
 d,2,5,6,1,4,6,5,
 {red,green}]
2> remove_duplicates(List).
[1,2,3,4,a,b,e,r,v,g,{red,green},d,5,6]
3>
```

Comment: removing duplicates doesn't give you uniques. Try out his example. If you want to remove duplicates sets:to_list(sets:from_list(List)) would probably perform better than this.

Comment: @MuzaayaJoshua The author wants to remove all elements that are not unique. [a, a, b, b, c, d] must leave only [c, d].

Comment: @MuzaayaJoshua author wants [foo, bar, foo, buzz, foo] => [bar, buzz]. Your solution gives [foo, bar, foo, buzz, foo] => [foo, bar, buz]. I proposed the sets solution because you said you used this in some of your projects.

Comment: I still stand by my word; Removing Duplicates does not give you the uniques in the list. Read the question again. Alexander doesn't want to remove duplicates, he wants to find out which elements appeared only once. At least I down vote with a proper reason.

Comment: Thank you for your code example, which of course helped me to learn Erlang a bit better. I would tend to agree with cashmere though to the extend that your example does indeed remove the duplicates, but at the same time does not give me the unique items.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
-module(util).

-export([unique_list/1]).

unique_list([]) -> [];
unique_list(L)  -> unique_list(L, []).

% Base Case
unique_list([], Acc) -> 
    lists:reverse(Acc);

% Recursive Part 
unique_list([H|T], Acc) ->
    case lists:any(fun(X) -> X == H end, T) of
        true  -> 
            unique_list(lists:delete(H,T), Acc);
        false -> 
            unique_list(T, [H|Acc])
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

unique(L) -> sets:to_list(sets:from_list(L)).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Please add a few words explaining how your code works and what exactly it does. This would strongly improve your answer.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to use a function with an "accumulator" that keeps track of what elements you already have.
So you'd write a function like

% unique_acc(Accumulator, List_to_take_from).

You can still have a clean function, by not exporting the accumulator version, and instead exporting its caller:

```
-module(uniqueness).
-export([unique/1]).

unique(List) ->
    unique_acc([], List).
```

If the list to take from is empty, you're done:

```
unique_acc(Accumulator, []) ->
    Accumulator;
```

And if it's not:

```
unique_acc(Accumulator, [X|Xs]) ->
   case lists:member(X, Accumulator) of
       true  -> unique_acc(Accumulator, Xs);
       false -> unique_acc([X|Accumulator], Xs)
   end.
```

2 things to note:
 -- This *does* use a list BIF -- `lists:member/2`. You can easily write this yourself, though.
 -- The order of the elements are reversed, from original list to result. If you don't like this, you can define `unique/1` as `lists:reverse(unique_acc([], List))`. Or even better, write a reverse function yourself! (It's easy).

Comment: This removes duplicates from a list, doesn't give you uniques. In the case statement you should do true -> unique_acc(lists:delete(X, Accumulator), Xs); . Even then it will only work for it item occurs even number of times and fail for odd # of occurrences.