# Choosing unique items from a list, using recursion

Tags: recursion, erlang

As follow up to yesterday's question [Erlang: choosing unique items from a list, using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391740/erlang-choosing-unique-items-from-a-list-using-recursion)

In Erlang, say I wanted choose all *unique* items from a given list, e.g.

```
List = [foo, bar, buzz, foo].
```

and I had used your [code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391740/erlang-choosing-unique-items-from-a-list-using-recursion) resulting in

```
NewList = [bar, buzz].
```

How would I further manipulate `NewList` in Erlang?

For example, say I not only wanted to choose all unique items from `List`, but also count the total number of characters of all resulting items from `NewList`?

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. 
I do however not want to manually enter the list again, i.e. I'm less interested in the character count function (that is secondary), but more into the fact how I could 'carry over' the results from making the original list unique onto automatically using the result for further operations, be they counting chracters or whatever. Thank you

Comment: Well, NewList is a variable, just use it. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Sure. Say my list is 

    List = [foo, bar, buzz, foo].

and I wanted the total no. characters of all unique items.

Further assume I had used *CODE* uniques(L) ->
    uniques(L, [], []).

uniques([], _, Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc);
uniques([X | Rest], Seen, Acc) ->
    case lists:member(X, Seen) of
        true -> uniques(Rest, Seen, lists:delete(X, Acc));
        false -> uniques(Rest, [X | Seen], [X | Acc])
    end. *CODE*

so get the unique items.

How would I need to amend this code smippet to also get the no. of characters (just as an example)?

Comment: uniques_and_chars(L)-> Uniques = uniques(L), num_chars(Uniques).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In functional programming we have patterns that occur so frequently they deserve their own names and support functions. Two of the most widely used ones are `map` and `fold` (sometimes `reduce`). These two form basic building blocks for list manipulation, often obviating the need to write dedicated recursive functions.

#### Map

The `map` function iterates over a list in order, generating a new list where each element is the result of applying a function to the corresponding element in the original list. Here's how a typical `map` might be implemented:

```
map(Fun, [H|T]) -> % recursive case
    [Fun(H)|map(Fun, T)];
map(_Fun, []) -> % base case
    [].
```

This is a perfect introductory example to recursive functions; roughly speaking, the function clauses are either *recursive cases* (result in a call to iself *with a smaller problem instance*) or *base cases* (no recursive calls made).

So how do you use `map`? Notice that the first argument, `Fun`, is supposed to be a function. In Erlang, it's possible to declare anonymous functions (sometimes called lambdas) inline. For example, to square each number in a list, generating a list of squares:

```
map(fun(X) -> X*X end, [1,2,3]). % => [1,4,9]
```

This is an example of [Higher-order programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_programming).

Note that `map` is part of the Erlang standard library as `lists:map/2`.

#### Fold

Whereas `map` creates a 1:1 element mapping between one list and another, the purpose of `fold` is to apply some function to each element of a list while accumulating a single result, such as a sum. The right fold (it helps to think of it as "going to the right") might look like so:

```
foldr(Fun, Acc, [H|T]) -> % recursive case
    foldr(Fun, Fun(H, Acc), T);
foldr(_Fun, Acc, []) -> % base case
    Acc.
```

Using this function, we can sum the elements of a list:

```
foldr(fun(X, Sum) -> Sum + X, 0, [1,2,3,4,5]). %% => 15
```

Note that `foldr` and `foldl` are both part of the Erlang standard library, in the `lists` module.

While it may not be immediately obvious, a very large class of common list-manipulation problems can be solved using `map` and `fold` alone.

#### Thinking recursively

Writing recursive algorithms might seem daunting at first, but as you get used to it, it turns out to be quite natural. When encountering a problem, you should identify two things:

1. How can I decompose the problem into smaller instances? In order for recursion to be useful, the recursive call must take a smaller problem as its argument, or the function will never terminate.
2. What's the base case, i.e. the termination criterion?

As for 1), consider the problem of counting the elements of a list. How could this possibly be decomposed into smaller subproblems? Well, think of it this way: Given a non-empty list whose first element (head) is X and whose remainder (tail) is Y, its length is 1 + the length of Y. Since Y is smaller than the list [X|Y], we've successfully reduced the problem.

Continuing the list example, when do we stop? Well, eventually, the tail will be empty. We fall back to the base case, which is the definition that the length of the empty list is zero. You'll find that writing function clauses for the various cases is very much like writing definitions for a dictionary:

```
%% Definition:
%% The length of a list whose head is H and whose tail is T is
%% 1 + the length of T.
length([H|T]) ->
    1 + length(T);
%% Definition: The length of the empty list ([]) is zero.
length([]) ->
    0.
```

Comment: Superb explanation. Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Trying to apply your guidance to a specific example, but still slightly unsure: Say my list is `List = [a, b, c, a].` and I require the _total no. characters_ of all _unique items_ only. Further assume I had now used `uniques(L) -> uniques(L, [], []). uniques([], _, Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc); uniques([X | Rest], Seen, Acc) -> case lists:member(X, Seen) of true -> uniques(Rest, Seen, lists:delete(X, Acc)); false -> uniques(Rest, [X | Seen], [X | Acc]) end.` to get the unique items. How would I change this code smippet to also get the no. of characters (just as an example)? Many, many thanks

Comment: Well, the output of `uniques` is another list, right? Pass that list as input to the fold suggested William Cummings below. :) Combining functions in `lists` can be very powerful. You can think of it as piping output from one Unix command to another.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a fold to recurse over the resulting list. For simplicity I turned your atoms into strings (you could do this with list_to_atom/1):

```
1> NewList = ["bar", "buzz"].
["bar","buzz"]
2> L = lists:foldl(fun (W, Acc) -> [{W, length(W)}|Acc] end, [], NewList).        
[{"buzz",4},{"bar",3}]
```

This returns a proplist you can access like so:

```
3> proplists:get_value("buzz", L).
4
```

Comment: Note that you'r reinventing map using fold, since you're taking a list and building a new list with 1:1 element mappings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build the recursion yourself for didactic purposes instead of using lists:

```
count_char_in_list([], Count) ->
    Count;
count_char_in_list([Head | Tail], Count) ->
    count_char_in_list(Tail, Count + length(Head)). % a string is just a list of numbers
```

And then:

```
1> test:count_char_in_list(["bar", "buzz"], 0).
7
```