# List help in Erlang

Tags: list, recursion, erlang

Hi I'm trying to write a function that returns a list with only the unique elements of a list eg. [1,2,3,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1] -> [1,2,3,4,5]

The only problem is that I can't use any other functions than this one I'm writing (not allowed to).

so:

**unique([H|T]) ->** any ideas?

(Has to do with recursion)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Erlang: choosing unique items from a list, using recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391740/erlang-choosing-unique-items-from-a-list-using-recursion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a short one without library function:

```
unique(L) -> unique (L,[]).

unique([],R) -> R;
unique([H|Q],R) ->
    case [Y || Y <- Q, Y =:= H] of
        [] -> unique(Q,[H|R]);
        _  -> unique(Q,R)
    end.
```

I used the =:= comparison, so 1 and 1.0 are considered as different.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty self explanatory, a find helper function that does the unique checking.

```
check_unique(List) ->
    check_unique(List, []).

check_unique([H|T], Acc) ->
    case find(H, Acc) of
    true ->
        check_unique(T, Acc);
    false ->
        check_unique(T, Acc ++ [H])
    end;
check_unique([], Acc) ->
    Acc.

find(E, [E|_]) ->
    true;
find(E, [_|T]) ->
    find(E, T);
find(_E, []) ->
    false.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest implementation, but simple.

```
unique(L) -> unique(L, []).

unique([], UL) -> UL;
unique([H|T], UL) ->
    case lists:member(H,UL) of
        true ->
            unique(T, UL);
        false ->
            unique(T, [H|UL])
    end.
```

The function produces the list in reverse. You can call `lists:reverse()`.

```
1> test:unique([1,2,3,1,2,3]).
[3,2,1]
2> test:unique([1,2,3,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1]).
[5,4,3,2,1]
```